# React app to display a dynamic clock with ntp client

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

I'm trying react-native-ntp-client, but fail with `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in xxx.js. As my node is v19.2.0.`

Are there any way to make an react app like https://time.is/utc?

```
const NTP = require('ntp-time').Client;
const client = new NTP('a.st1.ntp.br', 123, { timeout: 5000 });

async function sync() {
    try {
        await client.syncTime();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

sync();
```